# It does not work when copying and creating image of a server running a live Django app in the new server

Tags: python, django, amazon-rds, vmware

I have a live Django server running. It is running in one of the servers made from a virtual machine, with IP that ends with 13. 
From VMWare, I copied the image of server 13 and created a copy in a server with an IP that ends with 14 just to avoid the IP crash. 
As far as my understanding goes, because the whole image was copied, I should not be having any problems when I access the copied IP address but even after restarting the apache2, it is giving me the internal server error. 
According to log, it says

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '34.xxx.xx.xxx' (101)")
```

Because all our servers, once it leaves the firewall, uses one IP address, connection to AWS RDS should not be a problem as it the Django app in server 13 is working flawlessly.
What could be the problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ping your AWS RDS from new server (ip=x.x.x.14) if you have ping you must check your firewall on AWS and on-promise , NAT.